# Why does the OpenFileDialog not open?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have a C# application which has an icon in the system tray.
When the user right-clicks on it, it will show a menu.

1. open file
2. exit

When the user clicks `1. open file`, it will show (ShowDialog) a form with two buttons

1. open file
2. close

When the user clicks `1. open file`, it will do

```
OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
openFile.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
DialogResult result = openFile.ShowDialog(); // deadlock here
if (result == DialogResult.OK){
    // do some thing
}
```

At line 3 the application **deadlocks**

1. User can NOT interact with the form, it does NOT respond
2. OpenFileDialog does NOT show

Could you please help explain reason why this problem occurs?

**Update Answer**

1. The form which create icon in system tray is called from another thread.
2. I set: `thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`, OpenFileDialog will show.

Comment: When opening a modal dialog like the OpenFileDialog it is normal that you cannot interact with the parent form. Or are you saying that is the OpenFileDialog named openFile that is freezed?

Comment: @Steve when show OpenFileDialog, user can NOT interact with form which called OpenFileDialog. And OpenFileDialog does NOT show.

Comment: A MODAL dialog is by design MODAL. It block everything in the form chain before the call. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834799/winforms-programming-modal-and-non-modal-forms-problem If you are in a point of your code where you need a file input for your user, then there is no sense in continuing your code without that file.

Comment: So the real question is "Why does the OpenFileDialog not open?"

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer is you application win form or wpf application?

Comment: @GSP try to use the constructor overload that takes the owner form _DialogResult result = openFile.ShowDialog(this);_ Your OpenFileDialog is probably behind the main form window

Comment: Sounds like no message loop is running. Does your application ever call `Application.Run()` anywhere?

Comment: Does your `Main()` method have the `[STAThread]` attribute? If not, try adding it.

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434984/c-sharp-openfiledialog-thread-start-but-dialog-not-shown

Comment: @ChristA `OpenFileDialog` will work from a Console app as long as the Main() method has a `[STAThread]` attribute.

Comment: In program.cs, I call `Application.Run(new MainForm(validArgs));`. I tried to use [STAThread]. but it does not work

Comment: If you try that code in a Console app, it should work (as long as you reference `System.Windows.Forms` and use the `[STAThread]` attribute. Does it work for you if you try that?

Comment: @All, Thanks for your support, I found my mistake and **update answer**

Answer (score -2):

```
openFile.ShowDialog();
```

mean that will be opened modal window for current form(form where dialog box created)

Comment: This is not even close to an answer that will fix the problem of the OP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478476/c-sharp-openfiledialog-non-modal-possible read this and try to understand.

Answer (score -2):

Try opening the dialogue from a separate thread, with a callback for when it returns. ShowDialogue is blocking the current thread, as you're waiting for the response from the dialogue to continue with your application behaviour - this means your application is going to hang until it's complete.

Comment: Because then it won't be blocking the application from continuing.

Comment: Well, first of all I would expect the application to be blocked when a fileopendialog is shown, that's the normal behaviour. Second, if you don't want the dialog to block it,what about using `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`?

Comment: @Pikoh there is no Show for OpenFileDialog. However I concur with you that using a separate thread for this is a recipe for a disaster if not done well (and if possible at all). Some working code example could help

Comment: Steve you are right. There is no `Show` for OpenFileDialog (I've never tried to use it so I didn't realized it hasn`t). And that tells us something about how it should be used :)

Comment: @Steve what are the pitfalls it could fall into? I can't think of any and would welcome the reasoning why this isn't a good solution

Comment: Well for starters, it simply won't work by default - you'd have to set the thread's apartment model to STA instead of MTA.

Comment: @CallumBradbury I have never done it because there is no real sense in making an OpenFileDialog pseudo non modal creating it in a separate thread. However running UI elements in a different thread should be handled very carefully. If you can provide a working example perhaps I could re-examine my preconcepts

Comment: @MatthewWatson Cool, cheers - I'll have to do some playing about with STA and MTA

Comment: @CallumBradbury also look at [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834799/winforms-programming-modal-and-non-modal-forms-problem